# MongoDB schema design(mongoose): User, Event, several members and moderators by event

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have an app with a mongoDB. A user can create events. An Event has one or more members, and one or more moderators as well. I am trying to decide which is the best schema for this app. I'm using mongoose. I tried to think the "mongo" way but I ended up with a highly relational schema.

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
//user log in using facebook, what should I store here?
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user data:......

});


var eventSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String ,
    description:String,
    type:String,
    user_id:Number,
    created_at: {type:Date,default:Date.now}

});

var eventParticipantsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    users:Array,
    event_id:Number
});

var moderatorParticipantSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    users:Array,
    event_id:Number
});
```

Which would be a more NoSQL schema?. I read about using the User as the main object containing array of events and within the events array a prop for an array of moderators and another prop of an array of members

```
Users{
  events_array:{
      moderators_array:
      members_array:    
      }
}
```

but I read it was not recommended if you have to push into the contained arrays too many times. So, what would be a nice design for this app?.....Thank you very much....

Comment: NoSql schema design is up to your application. Main purpose is to get data from one collection to show one page or UI. If you need show User with events, then events should be user's prop. If you need show Event with User, then event should contain a prop to store User data. Data redundancy is allowed. P.S. do not duplicate all data, just fields you need.

Comment: If you want data consistent, NoSql may not be the best choice.

Comment: The thing is I'm expecting high inserción in my app and I need noSQL....I need both, to show all events from my users, and to show all users in one event.....should I need to store only the ids of events within the array of reventa in the user properties?... Please, I need a more detalles sugestión.same question with the members and moderators of an event.... Should I put only ids on those arrays and make a 2nd query?

Comment: I've been reading more and I don't know If Mongo is going to be the best for this case. Isnt there a noSQL motor that offers data relationship and json?

Comment: I'm going to start with postgreSQL that also comes with the Option of storing json...If I want to move to mongoDB in the future there are tools for that in case I have scalability....it seems that I need a lot of relationship use Mongo on this one

Comment: Yes, to performance high insertion, you should avoid update. You should find out which one is under high insertion, isolate it into a single collection. Then the others can be designed for display, show data in one find.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. I just started with postgres and we'll see how it goes xD